# 2020 Macbook Pro laptop screen freezing windows, but mouse and other screens functional

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I have a 13" MacBook Pro running macOS 13.1 Ventura (but the problem has been present since at least macOS 12).  Sometimes, quite randomly, the display on the laptop itself will "freeze."  I use quotes there because the mouse still moves, and allows me to interact with the applications.

The touchbar is functional and updates when I click around.  I can use other external screens just fine.  I can even drag windows from the laptop screen to the other screens and they work, but the frozen window is still on my laptop screen.  The only thing that ever changes on the laptop screen is the mouse.  I can move it around and click just like normal, but nothing else updates on that screen.

I can close the laptop lid, wait about 10 seconds, open it again, and then everything works again.

The problem persists through reboots, system updates, etc.  Any ideas?  So far I haven't been able to find any diagnostic information about this or why it is happening.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that the image on the screen, whatever happens to be, freezes but you can still move the mouse and interact with the Touch bar?  What if you try an external monitor, does it still happen?  One more thing, try running in Safe Mode and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: @Allan thanks for the comment.  The image freezes on the screen.  However, the contents of the screen can be interacted with, using the still visible and still functional mouse.  I am able to move things to an external monitor and continue using them as normal, but the laptop screen still shows a frozen image of the window that was there (even though that window is now on an external screen being interacted with, and updating)

As far as safe mode, it's hard to say because the issue itself is sporadic.  It's been at least two days since I've seen it.

Comment: Still a bit fuzzy on the freezing part.  If the display freezes but you can still interact…can you move a window but instead of redrawing  the window as it moves, it just leaves artifacts?  Like when you [win a game of Solitaire on Windows](https://cdn.ndtv.com/tech/gadgets/solitaire_winning_microsoft.jpg)?  Can you take a picture?  Also, when it freezes can you do a screen grab?

Comment: @Allan It still hasn't happened again, but when it does I totally will grab a screenshot for you.  But yes.  I can move a window, but I don't see anything move on the screen (other than the mouse cursor). So yeah, nothing on the main laptop screen redraws except for the mouse cursor.